# Why does NS3 build every time I run a file

Tags: ns-3

I am working on NS3 and I am using the ./ns3 cmake wrapper to run my .cc files. The issue is that the ns3 builds all the dependencies every time i run a file, even when there are no code changes. Is this expected? This is really hogging my time and I see in the NS3 manual that it should not build every single time, and builds only what is necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you report should not be happening, especially if you are using the latest ns-3.36.1 release.  If it is with that release or later, please file an issue with enough details for a maintainer to try to reproduce the issue.  In any case, you can suppress even checking whether a new build is needed by passing the `--no-build` option to `./ns3 run` command.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I am using the later 3.36. Using the no-build option does help, but adding the slightest of code change starts the entire build so I will raise an issue.

Comment: Make sure you are using ns-3.36.1, not ns-3.36, before you raise an issue. Some build system issues such as you are describing were the reason that ns-3.36.1 minor release was made.